# Issue on Adding Auto Click on Dynamically Added Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know jQuery uses this method to bind bind click event to dynamically created HTML elements:

```
$(document).on("click", "a" , function() {
  //$(this).DoSomrthing();
});
```

However this requires user clicks on the `a` to work. In my case I need to have a function like this, which automatically clicks the new elements:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
  $('.box').append('<a href="" class="b">Test</a>');
}

setTimeout(function () {
  $('a').each(function (e) {
    $(this).click();
  });
}, 5000);
```

Can you please let me know how to raise automatic click events here?

Comment: Why don't you just call the function directly?

Comment: `$(this).trigger("click");` should work

Comment: Your code should (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/9pn83qmc/) work as it is - although I can imagine it being very annoying for your users.

Comment: @RomainBar that's identical to the `$(this).click()` that the OP already has

Answer (score 1):

Delegate it from body

```js
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
  console.log('clicked')
});

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  $('.box').append('<a href="" class="b">Test</a>');
}


setTimeout(
  function() {
    //Changed here
    $('body a').each(function(e) {
      $(this).click();
    });
  }, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Why would this make any difference? The OPs code already works as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/9pn83qmc/

Comment: thanks brk but is it possible to pass class name `.b` instead of element `a` here?

Comment: @JJBOBO yes, just change the selector, but as I've said three times, your code is already working.